# React with JQuery

Tags: reactjs

I am rebuilding a project from JQuery、Bootstrap... to React and have some concept need to clarify.

A sample with JQuery:
I have an element which has a click function called ShowTarget and the function will use JQuery toggle.

```
 function ShowTarget() {
        $('#target').toggle("blind", 500);
    }
```

I know how to use React click event to show or hide the #target element but now I need the `("blind", 500)` transaction effect.

In this case, implement the transaction effect with CSS by myself or bind React with JQuery, which one is better?

And I see the `ReactTransitionGroup` in React official site, maybe this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a 'ref' to get access to the actual DOM node as explained [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html), then just call the jQuery function required.

```
let HelloComponent = React.createClass({
    clickHandler(){
    $(this.refs.h1).toggle("blind", 500);
  },
    render(){
    return (
        <div>
        <h1 ref='h1'>Hello, world!</h1>
        <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Fade</button>
      </div>
    ) 

  }
})


ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloComponent/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p757cbxp/

I've done similar with Bootstrap's Modal however its not recommended as you are changing the DOM without React's knowledge, but sometimes you just need existing code to work! [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530716/react-how-much-can-i-manipulate-the-dom-react-has-rendered) explains more about what is and isn't allowed in regards to DOM maniuplation without React's knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

I don't mean to be rude, but i would not recommend to use jQuery with React. At all.

Add a `className` value to your JSX element on click and animate it with a CSS transition or animation. How you add that className is up to you - you could store the clicked state in a flux store and then apply/remove the correspondent className based on it.

*Edited 16/03/2016:*

Some good tips were given in the comments. You can go about this in a multitude of ways. The outlined way is the most simple one in terms of standard web technologies. Certainly, there are a lot of abstractions that can simplify things. I would recommend those only after you know how the basic principles work.

To do the actual animation, you can write the transition/animation yourself or use libraries such as [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/).

React-based solutions like [ReactTransitionGroup or ReactCSSTransitionGroup](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) or the excellent [react-motion](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion) for spring-based animations are also a good choice. I just think one should grasp the basic concepts and start with them before using higher-level abstractions.

Comment: Thank you. I know using JQ in React in not recommend but in this case if I do not use the transaction effect which has been implemented by JQ then I need to implement it by myself.

Comment: I would not use jQuery for the purpose of animating elements. Use libraries like [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) to do so.

Comment: This is a good advise. I saw the `ReactTransitionGroup` in React offiical website, how about this?

Comment: I agree. Try hard not to use jQuery with React.  Btw [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) seems [cool](https://jsfiddle.net/p757cbxp/1/).