# how to see add symbol on end of every sentence in pre tag html in react js javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i am currently using pre tag , in pre tag  the text format is pretty raw. what i want to do is put something on end of each sentence in pre tag like the example below, how can i acheive this?

sample pre tag

```
<pre>
hello
good world
my name is
dan
</pre>
```

i want to add $ symbol at the end of each sentence like this

```
<pre>
hello $
good world $
my name is $
dan $
</pre>
```

how can i achieve something like this with the help of javascript and react js

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: i need it dynamic

Comment: But you haven't shown us your current effort?

Answer (score 1):

You could [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) along line breaks and [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the way you want it:

```js
for(let pre of document.getElementsByTagName("pre"))
  pre.innerHTML=pre.innerHTML.split("\n").join(" $\n");
```

```html
<pre>
hello
good world
my name is
dan
</pre>
```

Comment: how do i do this in react js

Comment: for that one you should show how that `<pre>` tag got there - because it should be done before that. as a developer of react writes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23572967/7916438): *Broadly speaking, you shouldn't manipulate by hand the DOM that React has created.* - then she continues that technically you can do anything, but the "React way" would be rendering the final content, so the one which already has the symbols inside.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simple text `replace` would suffice

```js
const pre = document.querySelector('pre');

pre.textContent = pre.textContent.replace(/\n/g,' $\n');
```

```html
<pre>
hello
good world
my name is
dan
</pre>
```